# WindowsFormsHost1.Child.Can't Focus

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

In a WPF control I have a hosted WinFormUserControl control via a WindowsFormsHost

Now, in the WPF control code I do:

```
void ShowWinFormUserControl() 
{
    ...
    windowsFormsHost1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    bool success;
    success = windowsFormsHost1.Focus();        // true
    success = windowsFormsHost1.Child.Focus();  // false
    success = windowsFormsHost1.Child.CanFocus; // false
    windowsFormsHost1.Select(); // any effect if first display

    // _arretSelection is the windowsFormsHost1.Child
    this._arretSelection.Select();  // any effect if first display
    ...
}
```

Why? How do I force focus on the WinFormsHost child?

Difference between the situation when the windowsFormsHost is still hidden
[image]

or already visible
[image]

Comment: See if this post helps http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2007/10/08/focus-management-and-mouse-wheel-hooking-on-winforms-by-using-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is the control enabled? If so, you can try to tab into the control using the [tabinto method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.tabinto.aspx)

Comment: This worked for me indeed when the `CanFocus` is `true`, when it was false I used the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and tried the tabinto again which worked (added a !hasfocuswithin check).